# I can't fit an image in a UIButton in Swift 5

Tags: swift, image, vector, uibutton, swift5

I have a vector (pdf) image stretch with the view while i want i want it to fit.

This : 
[image: camera]

Should be like this :
[image: camera]

I tried to change the contentMode in the storyBoard like this :
[image: camera]

And even directly in the code like this : 
`cameraUIButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

I also changed controls of the view to fill vertically and horizontally. But nothing works.

What else can I try ?

Edit :
Those are the constraints of the button :
[image: camera]

Edit 2 :
When i click on the button the image fit !!!!
Now what append when I click on the button that make the image fit ?
I already tried

```
        cameraUIButton.imageView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        cameraUIButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and it didn't work

Comment: You should change the content mode in the 4th tab, the attributes inspector. You'll see a list on the bottom. Also. you shouldn't add User Defined Runtime Attributes except if you really know what you are doing

Comment: I tried it too, but this content is only for the view so technically it doesn't affect the image inside the view

Comment: Are you using auto-layout constraints?

Comment: @SylvanDAsh No, the height of the button is fixed but width depend of the width of the super view. But it's not setted as an auto-layout constraints

Comment: @MathieuRobert so long as the image has `leading` and `trailing` constraints together with the `height` constraint, then `Aspect Fit` should work OK. In other words, you just need to make sure there are constraints to determine the width

Comment: @SylvanDAsh I added an edit with all the constraints on the button, i think i have all constraints you said, but the image still doesn't ```AspectFit```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, it's the same as here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/57905360/1952656

But we can't give the same answer to two differents question, so go check directly