# AspectFit image inside an UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift5

I have an image looking like this

[image: camera]

But it should look like this :

[image: camera]

I added the line : `cameraUIButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

It doesn't works BUT if i click on the button it fit !!
What append in swift when you click on the button that recalculate the fit of the image ?

I already tried

```
        cameraUIButton.setNeedsDisplay()
        cameraUIButton.imageView?.setNeedsDisplay()
        cameraUIButton.imageView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        cameraUIButton.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

and all in

```
viewDidLoad()
viewWillAppear()
viewDidAppear()
```

Nothing do what cliking on the button do, what else could i try ?

Comment: where the cameraUIButton you added, I mean in navigation bar or else

Comment: It's in a simple UIView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !!
You need to add

`cameraUIButton.imageView?.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true`

So the full code to aspectFit a vector image inside a button is :

```
cameraUIButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
cameraUIButton.imageView?.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true
```

I don't know why it's not `true`by default as it's turned to it if you click on the button or if you animate it.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `cameraUIButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit` it ensures that the image is scaled so as to fit the frame of the view, button in this case.

Try `cameraUIButton.imageView?.contentMode = .aspectFit` it will retain original image and not stretch it.

Comment: ```Type 'UIView.ContentMode' has no member 'aspectFit'```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
button.contentHorizontalAlignment = .fill
button.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: I tried it too, but didn't work, the only thing worked is ```cameraUIButton.imageView?.adjustsImageSizeForAccessibilityContentSizeCategory = true```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go on storyboard give it a fixed width and height
2. give is horizontal or vertical constraint according to your view.
3. if you do these step you will get your image, also it will work fine in all device, don't forget to check clipOutOfBounds

Comment: If you fixe width and height it will not adjust on device's screen width so it's not good. Also i found the solution, I just need to wait to check my own answer.

Comment: you can adjust it by giving content hugging priority, do what I said it will work, it worked for me, fixed width and height help you to keep your image in button, rest you have play with auto layouts